# general method to adapt all tail recursive algorithm to an iterative (or the opposite)

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, recursion, implementation

During a functional programming course, the professor explains to us that tails recursions calls could be considered as while loops calls (in a functional programming language):

ex:
this while loop:

```
void loopWhile(long long unsigned int n) {
    long long unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i <= n) {
        printf("%llu\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nFinish !!!\n");
}
```

could be equivalent to:

```
void loopWhileRec(long long unsigned int n, long long unsigned int acc) {
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("%llu\n", acc);
        printf("\nFinish !!!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("%llu\n", acc);
        loopWhileRec(n-1, acc+1);
    }
}
```

with acc=0.

So, with this thinking, it's possible to adapt some recursive algorithms to iterative version:

e.g:
level 1: factorial:

```
long long unsigned int factRec(long long unsigned int n, long long unsigned int res) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return res;
    }
    else {
        return factRec(n-1, n*res);
    }
}
```

with res = 1

method: replace argument res as a variable to multiply by i (of the for or while loop) and return the result:

```
long long unsigned int factIter(long long unsigned int n) {
    long long unsigned int res = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        res *= i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

level 2: fibonacci:

In these recursive version, there are more arguments:

```
unsigned int fiboRec(unsigned int n, unsigned int acc, unsigned int prev) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return acc;
    }
    else {
        return fiboRec(n-1, prev+acc, acc);
    }
}
```

with acc = 0 and prev = 1.

To realize the iterative version, we just need to replace arguments acc and prev by variables:

```
long long unsigned int fibo(long long unsigned int n) {
    long long unsigned int acc = 0;
    long long unsigned int prev = 1;
    long long unsigned int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = acc;
        acc += prev;
        prev = temp;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

the temp argument is used to get the previous content of acc, before the re-assignation to prev+acc. And we returns acc variable to get the result.

level 3: power function (my current problem):
In a functional programming book, I learned this function to compute x^n with a logarithmic time complexity:

```
unsigned int power(unsigned int x, unsigned int n, unsigned int acc) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return acc;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return power(x*x, n/2, acc);
    } 
    else {
        return power(x*x, (n-1)/2, x*acc);
    }
}
```

with acc = 1 at the beginning.

I would like to find a way to implement this tail recursive version to an iterative algorithm,more specifically, I would like to know a more general method that could work here, not just an algorithm already written.

So, I know I should to declare res = 0 to start,
but in the for / loop while, I don't know exactly how I should to do because all variables during recursive process are modified (x = x*x, n = n/2 or (n-1)/2 ...).

For the moment, I realized that, but it's not working:

```
long long unsigned int powerIter(long long unsigned int x, long long unsigned int n) {
    long long unsigned int acc = 1;
    long long unsigned int i = 0;
    long long unsigned int temp = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            x *= x;
            i /= 2;
        }
        else {
            temp = x;
            x *= x;
            i = (i-1)/2;
            acc *= temp;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

I just was wondering if I need to add different variables, or if it's possible to find an other way to code that.

This could be useful in languages with recursion limits.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what your problem with the last example is. Please *show* your attempt at coding the answer and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I add my first attempt. I start with assignation for the variable contains the result and I created a loop. My problem is: in this situation (pattern), how to assign the different elements, using recursive version, to get a working iterative version of the same algorithm.

Comment: I see your problem now. You are trying to map the recursion to the `for` loop. Don't. The recursion is analogous to the `while` loop. If the recursive version has `if (n == 0) return;` the iterative version should most probably have `while (n != 0) { ... }`. This is a way more straightforward mapping.